# Accesing files containing Spanish characters returns 404

Tags: php, apache, encoding, utf-8

I just implemented a new server, and everything is going great but the support for UTF-8 doesn't seem to fully work.

For example, I have the following photo: `José-Antonio.jpg` , the browser outputs it as `Jos%C3%A9-Antonio.jpg` but trying to access it, will return an `404` error code.

I do have tried both of the following settings in my `/etc/httpd/conf/http.conf/` file, but none seems to work:

```
#AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddDefaultCharSet ISO-8859-1
```

So any ideas what else could I try to fix this issue? Btw, I'm running a wordpress site.

Comment: you may get a better response on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RowlandShaw so I should write the question over there as well or wait for a moderator to move it?

Comment: You can flag it to ask for it to be migrated

Comment: Yes, better flag it to get it moved (*Edit:* I now flagged it, but you can flag as well so the moderator sees that you want that, too). This is also related to the file-system you are using, so you should share which operating system you're using and some of the file-system related system details.

Comment: it's a bit urgent, the matter... should I wait a little bit more to see if a moderator will move the question?